# Installing windows xp from a removable storage

Tags: windows-xp

i want to install windows xp from my flash disk but upon running DISKPART and LIST PART  my flash disk is not being listed.I soon find out its not supported on another forum.I tried unet bootin but i dont want to go that route.I have learn't that i can make my flash disk appear a hard drive but i am not sure since i have never done this before.

I am following this tutorial:  http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-install-windows-7-rc-on-acer-aspire-one-netbook/

If i present a usb stick as a hard drive,will i be able to install xp now?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this article : [Installing Microsoft Windows XP from usb device](http://wiki.eeeuser.com/windowsxpusb).

It lists 3 methods :

1. [flashboot](http://www.prime-expert.com/flashboot/) : Althrough shareware, it can do this one-time task in demo mode.
2. Using [USB_MultiBoot.cmd](http://reboot.pro/4900/)
3. Using nLited